# make xml element unique using xslt-3

Tags: xslt-3.0

Given the following sample xml, how could i make the RECORD ID element, and the TITLEID have unique values, starting from the value 1, and going on?

```
<CATALOG>
   <CD>
    <RECORD ID="109">
       <TITLEID>54</TITLEID>
       <ARTIST>Bob Dylan</ARTIST>
       <COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY>
       <COMPANY>Columbia</COMPANY>
       <PRICE>10.90</PRICE>
       <YEAR>1985</YEAR> </CD>
    </RECORD>
   <CD>
     <RECORD ID="187">
       <TITLEID>88</TITLEID>
       <ARTIST>Bonnie Tyler</ARTIST>
       <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>
       <COMPANY>CBS Records</COMPANY>
       <PRICE>9.90</PRICE>
       <YEAR>1988</YEAR> </CD>
     </RECORD>
</CATALOG>
```

expected result:

```
  <CATALOG>
       <CD>
        <RECORD ID="1">
           <TITLEID>1</TITLEID>
           <ARTIST>Bob Dylan</ARTIST>
           <COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY>
           <COMPANY>Columbia</COMPANY>
           <PRICE>10.90</PRICE>
           <YEAR>1985</YEAR> </CD>
        </RECORD>
       <CD>
         <RECORD ID="2">
           <TITLEID>2</TITLEID>
           <ARTIST>Bonnie Tyler</ARTIST>
           <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>
           <COMPANY>CBS Records</COMPANY>
           <PRICE>9.90</PRICE>
           <YEAR>1988</YEAR> </CD>
         </RECORD>
    </CATALOG>
```

My try was with xs:unique attribute, but I've not managed to get this working correctly

Comment: Please show us a well-formed XML input sample and result sample, having an opening `CD` tag and an opening `RECORD` tag closed first with a `CD` and then with a `RECORD` is not well-formed. And asking for XSLT help but mentioning a schema element `xs:unique` as a "try" sounds odd, look into `xsl:number` in any XSLT version or an `xsl:accumulator` if you are inclined to a pure XSLT 3 approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An XSLT 3 solution using an accumulator (https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#element-accumulator) is at https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6qVRKwn/0 and does

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy" use-accumulators="cd-count"/>

  <xsl:accumulator name="cd-count" as="xs:integer" initial-value="0">
      <xsl:accumulator-rule match="CD" select="$value + 1"/>
  </xsl:accumulator>

  <xsl:template match="RECORD/@ID">
      <xsl:attribute name="{name()}" select="..!accumulator-before('cd-count')"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="RECORD/TITLEID">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:value-of select="accumulator-before('cd-count')"/>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The classical solution would be to use `xsl:number` (https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#element-number), as in https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6qVRKwn/1:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:template match="RECORD/@ID">
      <xsl:attribute name="{name()}">
          <xsl:number count="CD"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="RECORD/TITLEID">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:number count="CD"/>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```